# Create a hierarchical dynamic grid with GWT

Tags: gwt, grid, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to create a grid in GWT representing hierarchical data.
The columns for the different levels would be the same and represent if a product is available for a category or not.

Something like that:

```
                      A | B | C | D
+ Product 1.1         X       X   X
  + Product 1.2       X       X   X
    + Product 1.3     X           X
+ Product 2.1             X
  + Product 2.2           X
...
```

I though I could use a CellTable and add Handlers to show/hide rows, but how shall I manage hiding all the descendant?

Comment: Did you look at the custom grid in the GWT showcase, [here](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid)? It shows an expandable row. I would guess that you'll want something like the `ShowingFriends` set that contains products that are currently showing.

Comment: Unfortunately the given example is not working for GWT 2.4: it doesn't support custom TableBuilders.
Anyway, I have created a table with custom columns. Just need to add an event listener to the rows but don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution:

As it is not possible to add a listener to the single rows (except for ClickHandler) nor to build custom rows (I am using GWT 2.4) I had to create a custom column.
I then created *NodeCell*, a simple variation of *ButtonCell* that shows a +/- button *before* the text.
If the column is a 'node', it will use *NodeCell*.
Clicking on the button fires an *ExpandEvent* on a *EventBus*.

Being unable to find a way to retrieve a widget representing the row, in the constructor of my custom table I've added a handler to the *EventBus* that changes the style of a row retrieved using *getRowElement()*. A parameter in the *ExpandEvent* provides the row index.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, work in MVC. Your controller catches the event, update the model, and then asks the dataprovider to refresh the display.

The simplest I can think of is when you catch an event asking to hide the descendant of, for instance, Product 2.1, cycle through your Model objects (a list I guess) and update the child element accordingly. Then refresh the cellTable using the appropriate methods on the dataProvider.